# Error encountered when approving a suggested edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

When reviewing suggested edits from the post page (i.e. not from the queue), if I'm the first reviewer and click <kbd>Approve</kbd>, the content *greys-out* but then nothing happens and I see this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at o (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=1c40da55cd4d:1)
    at Object.alternativeCallback (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=1c40da55cd4d:1)
    at Object.success (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=1c40da55cd4d:1)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

[image]

If I reload the page and open the suggested edit again, I see a banner saying that I already approved so the action did work correctly.

[image]

This doesn't happen if I'm the final approver and the suggested edit is applied.

It also doesn't happen when reviewing from the queue.

Comment: Repro'd this yesterday when rejecting, thought it was a one-off

Comment: I just tried this (MacOS Big Sur, Firefox 92.0.1) and got `Uncaught TypeError: t.currentQueueLimit is undefined
    o https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=1c40da55cd4d:1
    alternativeCallback https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=1c40da55cd4d:1
    success https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=1c40da55cd4d:1
    jQuery 4`

Comment: Corresponding MSE post: [Reviewing a suggested edit "inline" does not dismiss the popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371774/335251)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally looking into this and it's an easy fix, luckily. Unluckily, I'm the one that broke it. :-| I was trying to update the review count that appears at the top of the queue when each task is loaded (because it can change in some circumstances), but didn't account for the in-post popup case, where the count doesn't exist at all. The fix is in review now and will be out probably on Monday. Thanks for reporting.