# Suggested edit approval popup is not closed after actioned

Tags: bug

When I am actioning a suggested edit from the Edit link in a question the popup is not closed automatically. The popup content is grayed out and must close the popup manually.

[image]

In the browser's developer console I can see an error

```
review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=1bdfe8c60be7:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at a (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=1bdfe8c60be7:1)
    at Object.alternativeCallback (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=1bdfe8c60be7:1)
    at Object.success (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=1bdfe8c60be7:1)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Comment: Same as [Error encountered when approving a suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411847/error-encountered-when-approving-a-suggested-edit)